# I have deleted a table, by exporting over the same table, and selecting the 'drop destination table before insertion'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore, export

I understand this might not be the best forum, but I could sure use some help right about now. If not, please suggest a forum where I can.

I was trying to backup a table, by using the export wizard. I accidentally seleected the same table as source and destination. Add insult to injury, I chose the `drop destination table before inserting` option. Needless to say, I now have an empty table.

I am sure there are (must?) be some backups, but the support team is not available to help right now. Is there anything I can do to recover the said table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, we did have backups. I restored the backup on another server, and just copied the required table to the production database. Of course, I did it during such a time, where I was sure that no new records would have been saved. Just to be sure, I stopped the web application before doing this.

The idea came from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540773/174936) in the question that was [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540729/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-sql-server-table) by Darin Strait in the comments.